# Don't work correctly when clicking on stars

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have created a small code for rating system and I have used font awesome star in my form. It doesn't work correctly when I click on it. I want to make the rating system work correctly when I click on it.

This is the code i'm using:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
        // Handles the mouseover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).next('i').slideToggle('500');
             $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-star fa-star-o');
        },
        // Handles the mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).next('i').slideToggle('500');
             $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-star fa-star-o');
        }
    );
    
    function set_votes(widget) {
      jQuery('.star_' + widget).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    }
    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        $(star).prevAll().removeClass('ratings_over');
        $(star).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).next('i').slideToggle('500');
         $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-star fa-star-o');
   $(star).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
        $('#client_ratings').val( jQuery(star).attr('data-id') );
          var data_id =jQuery(star).attr('data-id');
         jQuery('.star_' + data_id).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');    
    }); 
    jQuery('.rate_widgett').each(function(i) {   
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        $(this).prevAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        var data_count = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $(this).find('.star_' + data_count).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    });
   });
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
    overflow:   visible;
    padding:    10px;
    position:   relative;
    width:      180px;
    height:     32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
    float:      left;
    padding:    2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
    color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
    font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
    width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
 <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
 <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
 <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
</div></div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

Comment: Define "correctly". What exactly did you expect it to do?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/font-awesome-star-ratings

Comment: this is the second time you post this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  $(".ratings_stars").hover(function() {
    var hasbeenvoted = $(this).hasClass("ratings_vote");
    var star = $(this).find("i");
    if (!hasbeenvoted && star.hasClass("fa-star-o")) {
      star.parent().prevAll().andSelf().find("i").addClass("fa-star").removeClass("fa-star-o");
    }
    if (hasbeenvoted) {
      star.parent().nextAll().andSelf().find("i").removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    }
  }, function() {
    var hasbeenvoted = $(this).hasClass("ratings_vote");
    var star = $(this).find("i");
    if (!hasbeenvoted) {
      star.parent().prevUntil(".ratings_vote").andSelf().find("i").removeClass("fa-star").addClass("fa-star-o");
    }
    if (hasbeenvoted) {
      star.parent().nextAll().andSelf().filter(".ratings_vote").find("i").addClass("fa-star").removeClass("fa-star-o");
    }
  });
  $(".ratings_stars").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var clicked = $(".ratings_choice").find('*[data-id="' +
      id + '"]');
    clicked.prevAll().andSelf().addClass("ratings_vote");
    clicked.prevAll().andSelf().find("i").addClass(
      "fa-star").removeClass("fa-star-o");
    clicked.nextAll().removeClass("ratings_vote");
    clicked.nextAll().find("i").removeClass("fa-star").addClass(
      "fa-star-o");
  });
});
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ratings_vote {
  color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
  font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
  <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
    <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

Comment: what is the role of + sign in front of star variable?

Comment: they were unnecessary, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only with CSS.

## Pure CSS Star Rating Widget

```
<fieldset class="rating">
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
<input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

And CSS

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
fieldset,
label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 20px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 10px;
}
/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
.rating > input {
    display: none;
}
.rating > label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f005";
}
.rating > .half:before {
    content: "\f089";
    position: absolute;
}
.rating > label {
    color: #ddd;
    float: right;
}
/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label,
/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #FFD700;
}
/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label,
/* lighten current selection */

.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label {
    color: #FFED85;
}
```

Follow this for [demo](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh)

Hope this helps

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
    // Handles the mouseover
    function() {
      $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
    }
  );

  $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
    var star = this;
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
  });
});
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
  color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
  font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.ratings_over {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
  <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
    <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

or:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
    // Handles the mouseover
    function() {
      $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
    }
  );

  $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
    var star = this;
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
  });
});
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
  color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
  font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.ratings_over {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
  <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
    <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

or

```js
      $('.ratings_stars').hover(
        // Handles the mouseover
        function() {
          $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
          $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
        }, function() {
          $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');

        }
      );

      $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
      });
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
  color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
  font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.ratings_over {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
  <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
    <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

or:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
    // Handles the mouseover
    function() {
       $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
     
    }, function() {
        $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
     

    }
  );

  $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
    $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
  });
});
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
  color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
  font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.ratings_over {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
  <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
    <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

or:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
    // Handles the mouseover
    function() {
      $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
       $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
     
    }, function() {
        $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('ratings_over');
     

    }
  );

  $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
    $('.ratings_stars').find('i').addClass('fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().find('i').addClass('fa-star').removeClass('fa-star-o');
  });
});
```

```css
.ratings_choice {
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
}
.ratings_stars {
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ratings_vote {
  color: green;
}
.ratings_choice {
  font: 10px verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
  width: 180px;
}
.ratings_over {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iva_ratings_choice">
  <div id="r1" class="ratings_choice">
    <a class="star_1 ratings_stars" data-id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_2 ratings_stars" data-id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_3 ratings_stars" data-id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_4 ratings_stars" data-id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
    <a class="star_5 ratings_stars" data-id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="client_ratings" id="client_ratings">
```

Comment: I like one of the code in this. I'll implement it. Thanks for the code.

Comment: @Pammm good to know :p